# Ease of rolling back from Spring Boot to regular Spring and viewing hybrid of Spring Context and configurations while using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am assessing whether spring-boot and how I could migrate to using it.

One question I have is whether a project that uses spring boot can be converted easily back to a regular spring project which uses the traditional spring configuration files if that is required. This would be useful in my mind for a few reasons.
1)  merging with legacy projects, because as I have read moving from legacy spring to spring-boot is somewhat tedious. 
2) Obtaining a view of the spring application context file and webapp configuration files to understand what the actual configurations being used are.

Another question I have is regarding the lack of application-context file, is there a way to have some kind of hybrid where there is still an application-context file that can be seen? Part of my concern is that spring-boot auto configures components without us knowing and learning how they are configured and work together.

Comment: Annotation-driven configuration was a feature added to Spring [back in 3.0](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api//org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html), so I'm leery of what your definition of "traditional configuration" is, since that was available as a traditional configuration style in '09.

Comment: Alright, thanks for that.  Now, I have to ask - what specifically are you wondering about?  You're asking two questions here and they're pretty divergent.

Comment: Perhaps you want to look at the autoconfiguration report?

Comment: yeah I guess part of my question was where those configurations that were previously in the springapplicationcontext whether it was in xml or programmatic. I have played around with spring-boot now and see that I still needed to add a @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.mypackage") to ensure that the rest controllers are picked up so that kind of answers some of my questions

Comment: @chrylis what is the autoconfiguration report is that what shows up in the logs when I run spring-boot:run goal from maven for example?

Answer (score 2):

Spring Boot provides *auto-configuration*.

When `@SpringBootApplication` is encountered, it triggers a search of the `CLASSPATH` for a file called `META-INF/spring.factories` which is just a regular text file that enumerates a list of Java configuration classes. Java configuration was introduced in 2006 and then merged into Spring 3 in 2009. So it's been around for a *long* time. These Java configuration classes define beans in the same way that XML does. Each class is annotated with `@Configuration` and therein you find beans defined using methods (factory methods, or provider methods) whose return value is managed and exposed via Spring. Each such provider method is annotated with  `@Bean`. This tells Spring to consider the method and its return value the definition of the bean.

Spring Boot *tries* to launch all the Java configurations it sees enumerated in that text file. It tries to launch RabbitAutoConfiguration.class, which in turn provides beans for connecting to RabbitMQ and so on. Of course, you don't want those beans in certain cases, so Spring Boot takes advantage of Spring framework 4's `@Conditional` mechanism to *conditionally* register those beans *only* if certain conditions are met: is a type on the `CLASSPATH`, is a property exposed through the environment, has there been another bean of the same type defined by the user, etc. Spring boot uses these to only create the RabbitMQ-specific beans if, for example, the dependencies that you would get from `org.springframework.boot`:`spring-boot-starter-amqp` are on the `CLASSPATH`. It also considers that the user may have provided a different implementation of `RabbitTemplate` in some othe rbean definition (be it XML or Java configuration) so it uses that if it's there.

These java configuration classes are the same sort of Java configuration classes you would write without Spring Boot. BUT... WHY? 80% of the time, the auto-configuration that Spring Boot provides is going to be as good or better than the configuration you would write yourself. There are only so many ways to configure Spring MVC, Spring Data, Spring Batch, etc., and the wager you take using Spring Boot is that the leaders and engineers on those various projects can provide the most sensible 80%-case configuration that you probably don't care to write, anyway.

So, yes you could use Spring Boot with existing applications, but you'd have to move those existing applications to Spring 4 (which is easy to do if you're using the `spring-boot-starter-*` dependencies) to take advantage of `@Conditional`. Spring Boot prefers: NO configuration, Java configuration, XML configuration, in that order.

If  you have an existing application, I'd do the following:

- find out what dependencies you can remove from your Gradle/Maven build and just have taken care of for you with the various `spring-boot-starter-` dependencies.
- add `@SpringBootApplication` to a root component class. Eg, if your package is `a.b.c`, put a class `Application` in `a.Application` and annotate that with `@SpringBootApplication`
- You can run it as a Servlet 3 application or in an embedded servlet container. It might be easier to just run in a standard servlet container as you take baby steps. Go to http://start.spring.io and make sure to choose `war` in the `packaging` drop down. Copy the ServletInitializer class and the specification from the `pom.xml` to ensure that your application is a `.war`, not a `.jar`. Then, once everything works on Spring Boot, `rm -rf` the Initializer and then revert the Maven build to a simpler `.jar` using the Spring Boot plugin for extra win.
- If your application has lots of existing configuration, import it using `@Import(OldConfig.class)` or `@ImportResource("old-config.xml")` on the `a.Application` configuration class. The auto-configuration will kick in but it will see, for example, that you may have already defined a `DataSource` so it'll plug that in in the right places. What I like to do now is just start the application up, see if everything's OK, then start removing code in my old Java or XML configuration. Don't remove your business code, but remove things related to turning on parts of Spring. Anything that looks like `@Enable..*` or `..:annotation-driven/>`. Restart and verify things still work. The goal is to let Spring Boot do as much of the heavy lifting as possible. Viewing the source is very handy here so you can see what Spring Boot will *try* to do for you. Spring Boot will log information on what `@Conditional` conditions evaluated to true for you. Simply provide `--Ddebug=true` wen you start the application to see the output. You could also `export DEBUG=true` then restart your IDE to run it as long as the environment variable is ivsible in your shell.

Comment: nice answer. Where can I learn the spring internals in this depth?